# Getting cookies from HTTP response cookies to Angular

Tags: angular, http, cookies

Im trying to get the server responded cookies to angular

```
component.ts

    this.api.doLogin(*mycredentials*).subscribe( res => {
    console.log(res);
}) 

service.ts

doLogin(*mycredentials*){
 return this.http.post(*myrequesturl* , {*mycredentials*});
}
```

its hitting to browser as this

[image]

how to get this informations on my console.log()?

Answer (score 0):

if your cookie is httponly then you won't be able to access it for security reasons else you can access it via **document.cookie**;

or you can use the following function.

**

```
function accessCookie(cookieName)
        {
          var name = cookieName + "=";
          var allCookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');
          for(var i=0; i<allCookieArray.length; i++)
          {
            var temp = allCookieArray[i].trim();
            if (temp.indexOf(name)==0)
            return temp.substring(name.length,temp.length);
          }
            return "";
        }
```

**